# Make .c file as a library error

Tags: c

I have a test.c file which contains main() function and some test cases and it cannot be modified it(such as adding "include *.h"). Then I have a foo.c file which contains some functions(no main() function). These functions will be tested through test cases in test.c file. What I'm going to do is use foo.c as a library and link it to test.c file. And here is the simple code.

test.c

```
//cannot modify
int main(){
    ...
    bar();
    ...
}
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h" //I will explain this below.
int bar(){
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to implement an interface using .h file, such as

foo.h

```
#ifndef _FOO_H_
#define _FOO_H_
    extern int bar();
#endif
```

Then using cmd line

```
gcc -c foo.c
gcc -o output test.c foo.o
./output
```

You may guess the result. There is a warning that "implicit declaration of function 'bar' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]". And the test.c file cannot run correctly.

Could someone help me about this? Thank you so much!

Comment: What the heck is `main.c`?

Comment: sry, it's a typo. It should be test.c. I have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

1. `test.c` has a call to `bar()` in it.
2. `test.c` doesn't have any declaration for `bar`, nor does it have an `#include` for a .h file that declares `bar`.
3. You are not allowed to change `test.c` in any way to add either a declaration or an #include.

This is a hard problem.  The C language *requires* there be a prototype/declaration for `bar` in `test.c`!  It can be written directly in the `test.c` file (write `extern int bar();` before you call it), or the declaration can come in from another file with an `#include` statement, but you *must* have it.

Luckily, GCC has a way to force an `#include` statement into a file while it's compiling the file.  You don't have to change `test.c` in order to make it start with `#include "foo.h"`.  This will solve your problem:

```
gcc -c -include foo.h test.c
```

Comment: Many people do not think about that one

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the declaration of `bar` in the test.c file:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

So that the compiler have the prototype in the translation unit, of test.c.

Comment: As I said above, test.c file cannot be modified.

Comment: @AATRSong The warning is because test.c called a function that it does not know its prototype. The only way is add it to test.c. "test.c cannot be modified" sounds a weird restriction, can you tell me why?

Comment: You assume I don't understand the warning? Good Job. Listen, the test file isn't implement by me. The person who have the test file just use it to test the foo.c file.